# Remote debug exe file that isn't running

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have configured remote debugger on my server and it works for attaching to running processes but I want to debug a .net 4.5 console application that doesn't stay running so it is not in the list of running processes when I try to attach to process in visual studio debugger.

The exe only takes a few second to run but I would like to be able to hit a breakpoint in the code while it is running on the live server.

How do I debug a remote console application?

Comment: Never tried this with a remote debugger but you could try calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch`. at the start of your process.

Comment: How would I call that?

Comment: Just like that: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` from within the program you want to debug. Maybe add a loop with `Debugger.IsAttached` until it's connected.

Comment: If I understood you question correctly, your problem is that the program doesn't run long enough for you to attach the debugger, right? So either wait a certain amount of time when your program starts (e.g. with `Thread.Sleep(20000)` or something) or wait until the debugger is attached (by checking `Debugger.IsAttached`) or actively launching the debugger (don't know if that's possible remotely but you can try with `Debugger.Launch`).

Comment: Ahh ok.  Debugger.IsAttached makes sense.  The launch confused me because I can't picture how it launched a debug session on my local machine.

Comment: Oh I see. No that's not what it does. It usually shows the "choose a debugger" dialog and I thought maybe it works with the remote debugger too.

Comment: Oh right, nice trick.  I will try to remember that.  Thanks